# How do I quicksort something based on its variable in local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, quicksort

Hi I am trying to sort some data in localStorage via its IDs.

The format of the data is this:
{"Brand":"Acura","Model":"Choose your model","Age":"1998","KM":"10","Name":"Harry","ContactInfo":"123456677"}

where I want to sort in lowest to highest order of the KM value.

My local Storage Key is register and this is the code that I am using:

```
function Qsort() {
    var mymain = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("register"));
    var result = quicksort(mymain, 0, mymain.length - 1);
    // the following line fo code shows the final result of the sorted numbers or strings
    console.log(mymain);
    console.log(quicksort(mymain, 0, mymain.length - 1));
    return result;
}

function quicksort(mymain, left, right) {
    var index;

    // checks if there are more than one numbers
    if (mymain.length > 1) {

    // partition will find a pivot then split leist in two either left of right. 
    // Left list contains everything that is smaller than the pivot and the right contians everythign larger than pivot
    index = partition(mymain, left, right);

    // will treat left side aas a new problem and will then run the sort
    if (left < index - 1){
        quicksort(mymain, left, index - 1)
    }

    // will treat right side as a new problem and will then run the sort
    if (index < right) {
        quicksort(mymain, index, right)
        }

    }
    return mymain
}

// Divides the whole function
function partition(mymain, left, right) {
    var pivot = mymain[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)],
        i     = left,
        j     = right;

    while (i <= j) {
        while (mymain[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (mymain[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(mymain, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

// swaps the values based on how high or low the number is
function swap(mymain, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
    var temp = mymain[firstIndex];
    mymain[firstIndex] = mymain[secondIndex];
    mymain[secondIndex] = temp;
}
```

What should I do the `var mymain` part so that it only picks up the value defined under KM.

Comment: Unless its too large a set... you really might want to try something like:
```function order(x, key) {
  return x.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a[key] - b[key]
  })
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the item at `"register"` in `localStorage` is an array you could simply do...

```
var mymain = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("register"))
var justKMs = mymain.map(function(data){ return data.KM; });
```

but that would return an array of just the KM values, so you would end up having to search through the `mymain` list to get the the rest of the data, which I assume is not what you want.

Another approach would be to add a "lookup" function to tell quicksort "how" to get the value you want to use for the sort. Let's define our lookup function signature as simply `function lookup( item ) => value` where `item` is the thing in the list currently being sorted, and `value` is the value to sort by.

The following is a version of quicksort from [computer-science-in-javascript](https://github.com/nzakas/computer-science-in-javascript/blob/master/algorithms/sorting/quicksort/quicksort.js) with the added "lookup" function.

```
// the swap function doesn't need to change
function swap(items, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
    var temp = items[firstIndex];
    items[firstIndex] = items[secondIndex];
    items[secondIndex] = temp;
}

// you will need to pass the lookup function into partition
function partition(items, left, right, lookup) {
    // here you need to use "lookup" to get the proper pivot value
    var pivot = lookup(items[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)]),
        i = left,
        j = right;

    while (i <= j) {
        // here is where you will do a lookup instead of just "items[i]"
        while (lookup(items[i]) < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        // also use lookup here
        while (lookup(items[j]) > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            swap(items, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

function quickSort(items, left, right, lookup) {
    var index;

    // performance - don't sort an array with zero or one items
    if (items.length > 1) {
        // fix left and right values - might not be provided
        left = typeof left != "number" ? 0 : left;
        right = typeof right != "number" ? items.length - 1 : right;

        // set a default lookup function just in case
        if (typeof lookup !== 'function') {
            // the default lookup function just returns the item passed in
            lookup = function (item) {
                return item;
            };
        }

        index = partition(items, left, right, lookup);

        if (left < index - 1) {
            quickSort(items, left, index - 1, lookup);
        }

        if (index < right) {
            quickSort(items, index, right, lookup);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

and then the "lookup" function for your dataset would be...

```
function kmLookup( data ) {
    return data.KM;
}
```

...ahh the power of higher-order functions

As a side note, if you aren't really married to quicksort you could take the lazy man option (or smart option depending on your point of view) and use the `sort` method on the Array prototype...

```
var mymain = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("register"));

// the sort function sorts the array in place,
//  so after this next line mymain will be sorted
mymain.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.KM - b.KM;
});
```

That would probably be the best solution assuming you are not working with a very very large dataset. [MDN Array.prototype.sort() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: This might be a stupid question but the part where  you wrote data, do I have to define what my localStorage key is or do I just leave it as data?

Comment: Which time are you referring to? If you are talking about the first code block, `mymain.map(function(data){ return data.KM; })`, **data** is an argument to the callback function passed into [**Array.prototype.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and would represent one object with the structure `{ "Brand":"Acura", "Model":"TLX", "Age":"1998", "KM":"10", "Name":"Harry", "ContactInfo":"123456677" }`. I was assuming the JSON returned by `localStorage.getItem("register")` evaluates to `[ data, data ... ]` where data is as you described.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense sorry I'm new to javascript I don't know all of the things like the data argument and so on.

Comment: If this solved your problem @JishnuKher I would love to get another "accepted answer" under my belt!